# How do I compile Bitcoin Core to be more portable?

Tags: bitcoind, make

Background: I compile bitcoind on one system but run it on another. When I compiled bitcoind 0.19.1 some time back using the following method, I was able to run bitcoind and bitcoin-cli on the target system without issue

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --disable-wallet --disable-tests --disable-bench --disable-gui --enable-util-tx=no --prefix=$HOME/bitcoind/x64 --exec-prefix=$HOME/bitcoind/x64
make && make install
```

Today I compiled v0.20.0 using the same method. If I run ./bitcoind -version on the system I compiled the binary it runs fine, but if I take the binary to my target system I get the following error:

```
./bitcoind: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_filesystem.so.1.67.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The binary seemed to be portable last time, and the pre-compiled binary I download from the Bitcoin Core team runs fine.

Note that on the target system `libboost-filesystem-dev` and `libboost-filesystem1.67-dev` are not installed, this is likely the source of my error. That said, running the pre-compiled binary from the Core team runs, so why doesn't mine?

Can someone help me understand if I did something wrong or if I need to add ./configure flags to make the binary more portable? Specifically what I likely did differently than the core developers that made my binary fail where theirs worked?

EDIT 1: Running `./configure --enable-static` or `./configure LDFLAGS=-static` does not result in a portable binary either.

Also note that installing libboost-filesystem library with apt does fix the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the binaries that you build are dynamically linked. This means that they use libraries installed in standard search paths on your computer. What you want is a statically linked binary where those libraries are packaged together with the binary.

Bitcoin Core achieves this by using the "depends" system. Documentation for this can be found [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/depends) and in the [windows cross compilation docs](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-windows.md#building-for-64-bit-windows).

Basically, you `cd` into the `depends` directory, run `make` in there, then back in the root directory, you configure and point to the configuration stuff produced by the depends system, and when you compile with `make`, it will use the libraries build in the depends system and be statically linked.

For example, you might do these commands:

```
cd depends
make HOST=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
cd ..
./autogen.sh
CONFIG_SITE=$PWD/depends/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/share/config.site ./configure --prefix=/
make
```

`x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` is the platform that you want to build binaries for. The depends system will create a directory in `depends/` with that name. That directory contains the depend system's build results.

The resulting binaries should be portable.

Comment: That did it, thanks! I ran make in the depends directory as you mentioned, but changed the ./configure line to the following: ./configure --prefix=$PWD/depends/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu and it worked great

Comment: @Mike this will move your binaries to `$PWD/depends/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` right?